# Query on usage of IF EXISTS, WHERE in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have recently started learning SQL. I have a query on usage of INSERT INTO with WHERE condition.
For example, I have a below table called Tbl_OrderDetails.
I would like to add new rows (same CustID with orderID of 100) whenever the orderID value is 50.
In this case,  CustID 3, 4, 5 have orderID value of 50. So I want to add 3 rows with orderID as 100. Since CustID- 5 already has OrderID of 100, I should not be adding it again, resulting in addition of only 2 rows.

| CustID | OrderID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 4 | 50 |
| 5 | 50 |
| 5 | 100 |

Result should be below

| CustID | OrderID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |
| **3** | **50** |
| **3** | **100** |
| **4** | **50** |
| **4** | **100** |
| **5** | **50** |
| 5 | 100 |

I tried a combination of IF EXISTS, INSERT INTO and WHERE but nothing seems to work. I cannot figure out how to apply the concept to my problem. Any help is appreciated.

I tried the below and it does not obviously work because I am not sure how to populate VALUES.Also, how do I make sure not to add a duplicate entry of 100 if it is already present?

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tbl_OrderDetails WHERE OrderID = 50)
INSERT INTO Tbl_OrderDetails
**VALUES(CustID,100)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat.

One is

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_OrderDetails
            ([CustID],
             [OrderID])
SELECT [CustID],
       100
FROM   Tbl_OrderDetails
WHERE  orderID IN ( 50, 100 )
GROUP  BY [CustID]
HAVING MAX(orderID) = 50
```

It finds rows where the orderID is 50 or 100 as these are the only ones that affect the result, groups them by customer id and keeps the groups where `MAX(orderID)` was `50` (so there was no `100` row).

Then inserts rows for those customer ids.